# How to make goroutines output in multiple different consoles?

Tags: go, user-interface, console, output, goroutine

I am practicing using goroutines and found that if both goroutines are printing at the same time, it becomes difficult to read.

```
func main() {
    s1 := rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
    r1 := rand.New(s1)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    t1 := func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            time.Sleep(time.Microsecond * time.Duration(r1.Intn(100)))
            fmt.Println("T1 : ", i)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }
    t2 := func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            time.Sleep(time.Microsecond * time.Duration(r1.Intn(100)))
            fmt.Println("T2 : ", i)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }
    wg.Add(2)
    go t1(wg)
    go t2(wg)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Output:

```
T1 :  0
T2 :  0
T2 :  1
T1 :  1
T1 :  2
T2 :  2
T1 :  3
T2 :  3
T1 :  4
T2 :  4
T1 :  5
T2 :  5
T1 :  6
T2 :  6
T2 :  7
T1 :  7
T2 :  8
T1 :  8
T1 :  9
T2 :  9
T2 :  10
T1 :  10
......
```

Is there any way to open multiple consoles and let two goroutines output in different consoles?

Comment: It may be possible, but how to do it will depend on which operating system you're using.  Also, I assume by "console", you really just mean separate text windows?

Comment: I understand it can be confusing at the beginning. I suggest to just, little by little, get used to it. After a while it will become second nature. You can always filter the output by first redirecting to a file with `tee` and then using `grep`.

Comment: @Flimzy Yes, just two windows that can display the outputs in real-time.

Comment: @marco.m I don’t want to output these to the hard disk, because when I am developing a program, there may be a lot of meaningless output, and I don’t want to save these meaningless things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You may use a simple **TCP terminal server**- first run this TCP terminal server and you don't need to close it as long as you need ( or just use **Netcat Command**: `nc -l 8080` then goto #2 and write to this TCP connection e.g. "127.0.0.1:8080"):

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for {
        w1, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        io.Copy(os.Stdout, w1)
        w1.Close()
    }
}
```

2. Then add this to your code:

```
    w1, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer w1.Close()
```

3. Then use `w1` as your another `io.Writer` in your code e.g. `fmt.Fprintln(w1, "T1 : ", i)`, an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    w1, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer w1.Close()

    // your code:
    s1 := rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
    r1 := rand.New(s1)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    t1 := func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            time.Sleep(time.Microsecond * time.Duration(r1.Intn(100)))
            fmt.Fprintln(w1, "T1 : ", i)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }
    t2 := func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            time.Sleep(time.Microsecond * time.Duration(r1.Intn(100)))
            fmt.Println("T2 : ", i)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }
    wg.Add(2)
    go t1(wg)
    go t2(wg)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a workable solution, but I am looking for something that can run in one single program and locally. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I mean ... this solution needs to startup 3 programs and pass the message through TCP connections. but what I am looking forward to was to run only 1 program, and the program opens multiple terminal and output messages.

But you are right, this solution can make the program easy to transfers to another TCP terminal which is better than I thought.

Comment: also : netcat (`nc -l <someport>` to have it running as a listener) is a pretty standard way to dump something coming from a local network port

Comment: a word of caution with UDP : you may miss packets, if the sent payload exceeds the size of your read buffer, you miss data, there won't be such thing as `EOF` on the receiving end, etc ... it's probably ok for local debugging, but you have to know that "not seeing a line" may just be "a packet was lost"

Answer (score 0):

`fmt.Print*(...)` functions are wrappers for `fmt.Fprint*(os.Stdout, ...)`. If you want to make two goroutines write to distinct writers, one first step in your code is to provide the writer they should use :

```
    t1 := func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, out io.Writer) {
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            time.Sleep(time.Microsecond * time.Duration(r1.Intn(100)))
            fmt.Fprintln(out, "T1 : ", i)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }

    ...

    // for starters : keep using the same os.Stdout writer
    go t1(wg, os.Stdout)
```

Instead of a raw `io.Writer`, you may want to pass something to which you can log ; the standard library has the `log.Logger` struct :

```
    t1 := func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, l *log.Logger) {
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            time.Sleep(time.Microsecond * time.Duration(r1.Intn(100)))
            l.Println(i)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }

    ...

    // all logging libraries will allow you to specify some option which you can tune :
    l1 := log.New(os.Stdout, "T1 : ", log.Ltime) // will prefix all messages with "[time] T1 : "
    go t1(wg, l1)

    // this allows you to write :
    l2 := log.New(os.Stdout, "T2 : ", log.Ltime) // will prefix all messages with "[time] T2 : "
    go t2(wg, l2)
```

You may look into golang logging libraries for more features -- don't spend too much time on choosing a logging framework for a quick throwaway project, though.

---

Now that you have an explicit way to pass two distinct writers (or loggers) to your goroutines, choose whatever suits your need to write to :

- have goroutine 1 log to Stdout and goroutine 2 log to Stderr
- log to `file1` and `file2` -- just run `tail -f file2` in some separate terminal to get a "live view" of the output
- `io.Discard` is a golang built-in equivalent of `/dev/null`
- log to a named pipe, a unix socket, a tcp connection ...